# Vue.js can't use v-model

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, v-model

So I want to send this `<p class="valikud" v-model="post.store"> {{body}} </p>` to my MongoDB database, but I can't send it because `<p></p>` is not allowed with v-model. I need to use v-model to send things to my database. To anybody got any suggestions. I really don't know what to do.

Comment: You want to send the element with its content?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the whole thing, for whatever reason that may be, you would have to make it all a string.

`const sendToDb = '<p class="valikud" v-model="post.store"> {{body}} </p>'`

I can't for the life of me think of a use case for this though. Would it be possible to show what you want to save, then how you intend you use that data once you pull it form the database? there may be a better way to achieve what you want.